In the pesach Seder when we talk about מעשה שהיה בבני ברק. Why were the students not with their rebbeim?
In the pesach Seder when we talk about מעשה שהיה בבני ברק. Why were the students not with their rebbeim?
As it says in the Seder רבותינו הגיע זמן קריאת שמע של שחרית. This clearly means that they weren’t with them during the actual Seder since it says that “they came to tell them”? Why were they not with them in the first place?

Maybe they were with their own families? Why should they have been with there?

The Gemara (Pesachim 108a) discusses whether a student should recline in his teacher's presence, and the halachic conclusion is that he should not. Maybe that's why they didn't want to be there.

This was the post Seder conversation.
